# Jquery not working on Heruko

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook-javascript-sdk, bots

i made a facebook bot using javascript, deployed it to heroku and it workes just fine. When i tried to make an AJAX call to API.AI using Jquery, it didn't work.

I know that i need to import Jquery in order for it to work, so i have only two ways  in mind for it to work:

1. import Jquery to the bot somehow (already tried copying the entire Jquery code to the Heruko repository)
2. change the Jquery AJAX code to vanila javascript (I dont know how)

here's my ajax call, thanks in advance!

```
var accessToken = MY_ACCESS_TOKEN;
var baseUrl = "https://api.api.ai/v1/";
var apiResponse;


function send() {
            var text = "pizza with hot sauce and thin crust";
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: baseUrl + "query?v=20150910",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                headers: {
                    "Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken
                },data: JSON.stringify({
                    query: text,
                    lang: "en",
                    sessionId: "<any random string>"
                }),
        success: function(data) {
                    apiResponse = (JSON.stringify(data["result"]["fulfillment"]["speech"],null, 2));
          console.log(apiResponse)
                },
                error: function() {
                    console.log("Internal Server Error");
                }
      })}
send()
```

Comment: i tried. but i don't know how to pass all the values

Answer (score 0):

You can use [XMLHttpRequest](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/dom_httprequest.asp) if you wanna send the AJAX request in pure JavaScript. `$.ajax()` of jQuery is basically a wrapper for [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)

Comment: i tried, but i dont know how to pass all the values properly

Comment: carefully go through the documentation. you'll get it.

Comment: I tried it, but i doesn't have examples. i know the basic syntax of an XMLHttpRequest, i simpoy dont know where to put the type,headders,etc...